# Monolog handler ignoring yaml level

Tags: symfony, logging, monolog

In Symfony 4.3 using Monolog, I have created a custom handler to push logs to AWS Firehose. Here is the constructor:

```
class FirehoseLogHandler extends AbstractProcessingHandler {

public function __construct(
        FirehoseClient $firehoseClient,
        FormatterInterface $formatter,
        $streamName,
        $level = Logger::INFO,
        $bubble = true
    ) {

        $this->firehoseClient = $firehoseClient;
        $this->streamName = $streamName;
        $this->formatter = $formatter;

        parent::__construct($level, $bubble);
    }
```

And here is my `monolog.yaml` config:

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    firehose_handler:
      type: service
      id: kinesis_stream_handler

    main:
      type: stream
      handler: firehose_handler
      level: error
      channels: ["!event"]

services:
  kinesis_stream_handler:
    class: App\Logger\Handler\FirehoseLogHandler
    arguments:
      $firehoseClient: '@aws.firehose'
      $formatter: '@App\Logger\Formatter\FirehoseLogFormatter'
      $streamName: 'firehose-stream-test'
```

The problem that I am having is that the `$level` is always set to `Logger::INFO` (200), or whatever is set in the constructor. It seems to be ignoring what is set in the yaml config.

What am I doing wrong here? I know I could always add `$level: 400` to the service declaration but that doesn't seem to make much sense. Appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlers defined as `type: service` are used strictly as-is, since they are instances you have already constructed. They are not passed any arguments from the main monolog configuration; that would only apply to services it is constructing for you. So you do need to add `$level` as an explicit argument to your custom handler for this reason.

There may be some further confusion stemming from your `main` handler definition. While `handler` is a valid configuration key, it does not apply to a `stream` handler as it only makes sense for handlers that wrap others, such as `filter`. So that is simply being ignored.

The full list of handler types and what configuration keys actually apply to each can be found in the code [here](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L25).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Good explanation. Just so that I get this right, there is no real way to extend Monolog to create a new handler `type`?

Comment: There is not. That would have to be added to the monolog-bundle Configuration class, and there is not really a clean way to extend that as far as I'm aware.